# Related the property of two points contained in the same component

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, connectedness

Let $\gamma:[0;1]\to\mathbb{R}^2$ be Jordan curve and $p,q\in\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\mathrm{Im}(\gamma)$. Suppose there exists $\alpha:[0;1]\to\mathbb{R}^2$ join p to q, $\alpha$ is not intersect with $\gamma$. Proof if $\mathrm{Im}(\alpha)\cap\mathrm{Im}(\gamma) =\emptyset$ then $p$ and $q$ are contained in a component of $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\mathrm{Im}(\gamma)$.

Any hint will be appreciate.

Comment: This is a consequence of the Jordan Brouwer separation theorem, which uses homology theory. Are you familiar  with it?

Comment: you can say precisely, thanks

Comment: Actually, $\mathbb R^2 \backslash \operatorname{Im}(\gamma)$, by the Jordan Brouwer separation theorem, consists of two path connected components, one "inside", therefore bounded and one "outside", therefore unbounded. Now, if $p,q$ are path connected, which is what the $\alpha$ is : it's a path, then since $\alpha$ is not intersecting $\gamma$, it's lying inside one of these components. Since $p,q$ are path connected, they lie inside the same path connected component : therefore, both are either inside or outside the curve. However, without the theorem, it's hard!

Comment: I believe you're mistaken. Suppose the question had been "$X$ is connected. $Y$ is a subset of $X$. $\alpha$ is a path in $X \setminus Y$ from $p$ to $q$. Show that $p$ and $q$ are in the same component of $X \setminus Y$." That'd still be true, and the proof is straightforward (indeed, it's what I wrote in my answer). The "Jordan curve" assumption here is a red herring. And this claim is (overall) far weaker than the Jordan Curve theorem, which asserts that the complement of a Jordan curve has exactly **two** components, one of which is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose not. Let $X = \Bbb R^2 \setminus \mathrm{Im}(\gamma)$.

Then since $p$ and $q$ are in different components of $X$, we know that there are open sets $U, V \subset X$ with $p \in U$ and $q \in V$ and 
$$
U \cap V = \emptyset\\
U \cup V = X.$$

Look at $U' = \alpha^{-1}(U)$, and  $V' = \alpha^{-1}(V)$.

These are open sets in $[0, 1]$, with $0 \in U', 1\in V'$, and
$$
U' \cup V' = [0, 1]\\
U' \cap V' = \emptyset.
$$

They thus show that the unit interval is not a connected set; that's a contradiction.